# Fixed-points in block ciphers; why don't they indicate a vulnerability?

Tags: block-cipher, known-plaintext-attack, chosen-ciphertext-attack, attack

I've seen a few questions here on fixed-points in ciphers, most asking about the possibility and existence. Most of the answers however pointed out that **fixed points are not exactly a security threat**. Googling about it didn't fetch me much. All I found was this [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=dPKqCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA70&ots=4IUCxDOHs3&dq=why%20are%20fixed%20points%20not%20a%20security%20threat&pg=PA70#v=onepage&q=why%20are%20fixed%20points%20not%20a%20security%20threat&f=false), which stated it well but does not go on and explain it why!

---

**My thoughts (from an attacker's perspective)**

If I find out that the block that I captured is a fixed-point, **I know the `pText` as well as `eText` for this key**. So it'd certainly help me crack it faster (both chosen-plaintext-attack and chosen-ciphertext-attack). Additionally, I know that the number of keys that result in such a fixed-point are very few. **So maybe there is a way for me to get the possible keys given the fixed-point.**

My **assumption** was that it'd be **easy for the attacker to find out that the captured block is a fixed-point** because it retains all of the original message's pattern. Also I **assumed that the relation from fixed-point to key is quite obvious**.

---

So it seems this attack is not considered a threat because my assumptions are wrong (one or both). What am I missing?

Comment: The probability of there being a fixed point is very low, for most keys there will not be one. If a cipher had a fixed point for EVERY key, then that would be bad, but most likely only a single fixed point per key exists, and only for a handful of keys

Comment: For a random permutation, the probability of picking a key with a fixed-point is 63%. Inferred from the [link.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics#Number_of_permutations_that_are_derangements)
Also can we say anything about the number of fixed points? I guess we can't because that's going to random...

Comment: I should have been more clear, I was not talking in a statistical sense, but rather in a "for the bulk of inputs, which is a fraction of the cipher's possible inputs, the chance of one of them having a fixed point is small" sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intuitively, the reason fixed points are not a problem is the same reason that zeros in a one time pad are not. Because the transform is supposed to be random, a ciphertext that looks like plaintext could be that plaintext... or it could be any other plaintext. With proper encryption they are all equally likely.

> If I find out that the block that I captured is a fixed-point, I know the `pText` as well as `eText` for this key.

Yes, but how would you find out that it *is* a fixed point? By knowing that the plaintext and ciphertext blocks are equal. I.e. this is not additional information.

> Additionally, I know that the number of keys that result in such a fixed-point are very few. So maybe there is a way for me to get the possible keys given the fixed-point.

The number of keys with that particular fixed point depends on the key and block sizes. E.g. with AES-256 you'd expect about $2^{128}$ keys with any fixed point you want. In the case of AES-128 it is true that a fixed point would likely be unique to one or two keys. However, there is no way to exploit that knowledge.

If you know $E_k(x)=x$, you can iterate all keys testing for that. But you can do the same if you know $E_k(x)=y$ for some other $y$. So the fact that it is a fixed point does not make key recovery any simpler, unless the internal structure of the cipher is somehow weak with regard to this fact.

So...

> My assumption was that it'd be easy for the attacker to find out that the captured block is a fixed-point because it retains all of the original message's pattern.

That assumption is wrong, because there are supposed to be many other blocks that produce patterns that *aren't* in the original message. The probability that $D(x)=x$ should not be higher if $x$ has patterns.

> Also I assumed that the relation from fixed-point to key is quite obvious.

It is not at all obvious. There could be a relation, but that should be considered a weakness in the cipher.